# combinatorial matrix

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I have a matrix like this:

X marks the blank spot

```
A A A A
B B B B
C C C C
D D D X
```

How many rearrangement are possible ?
And is there a formula? [this part answered].

If you follow the link, it says 24964 cells.
I do not understand how he get this number ?
[walking distance heuristic](http://www.ic-net.or.jp/home/takaken/e/15pz/wd.gif)

For a matrix like this :[15 puzzle]

```
 1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8
 9 10 11 12
13 14 15  X
```

there is 16! possibility to rearrange them

Comment: I am sorry but I can't understand your question. Do you want to know in how many ways you can take the contents of those matrices and rearrange them into another matrix? Is that it?

Comment: Yes that is it.

Comment: @RSerrao There are16 factorial possible arrangements, for the second matrix(with number). I want to know how many there are for the first one (with letters), and how do you calculate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that there is a direct bijection between a matrix of the form $\begin{bmatrix}a_1&a_2&a_3&a_4\\a_5&a_6&a_7&a_8\\\vdots&&\ddots&\\\vdots&&&\ddots\end{bmatrix}$ and a string of the form $a_1a_2a_3a_4a_5a_6a_7a_8\dots$

Your question becomes "How many rearrangements of the **string** `AAAABBBBCCCCDDDX` exist?"

This is counted directly using [Multinomial Coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients) as being:

$$\binom{16}{4,4,4,3,1} = \frac{16!}{4!4!4!3!1!} = 252252000$$

Note: this counts the number of arrangements, not the number of [orbits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Orbits_and_stabilizers) of the puzzle, i.e. the number of arrangements which can't be transformed into one another via a sequence of moves such as sliding tiles.

Comment: Thank you for the multinomial coefficients article. It is helpful in my general understanding of the problem at hand.

Can you explain to me why in the walking distance article, he says there are 24964 cells. What is that number the result of, if not the set of unique arrangements possible?

Answer (score 0):

To obtain 24964, do not distinguish between matrices which can be obtained from each other by permuting elements in the same row. So, for example, the following matrices are all equivalent:

```
A A A B      A B A A      B A A A
B B B A      B A B B      A B B B
C D C D      D D C C      C C D D
D C C x      C x C D      D x C C
```

Then 24964 is the number of equivalence classes of such 4x4 matrices, with 4 'A' elements, 4 'B' elements, 4 'C' elements, 3 'D' elements and one 'x' element. The permutation of elements in the same row is irrelevant; it only matters how many are there elements of each type in a given row.

See also [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/108631) on Code Review Stack Exchange which mentions the walking distance heuristic.